How to Check if LWS (lightning web security) is enabled inside Apex or LWC
I would like to experiment with dynamic LWC components in my managed package.
I also would like to keep the option for some clients to use my package in case some other package requires keeping the LWS turned off.
So, for that purpose, I would like to be able to go with 2 different ways in the same LWC component - in one case use direct c-component inclusion in my html and in the other use the dynamic approach.
Is there a way to get that information inside LWC or via Apex controller call?
but in case

We articulated how to approach this via the developer blog here
In nutshell you can use below code
function hasLightningWebSecurityEnabled() {
try {
  new Worker();
 } catch ({ message }) {
    if (message.includes('Lightning Web Security: Cannot create Worker')) {
       return true;
   }
 }
  return false;
}

You can use something like below
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class LwsChecker extends LightningElement {
   hasLightningWebSecurityEnabled() {
    try {
      new Worker();
    } catch ({ message }) {
      if (message.includes('Lightning Web Security: Cannot create Worker')) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}
connectedCallback() {
    let lwsIsEnabled = this.hasLightningWebSecurityEnabled();
    console.log(lwsIsEnabled);
    if (lwsIsEnabled) {
    //     do LWS-only stuff
    } else {
       //     fall back to not using LWS-only features
     }
  }
}


This no longer works. Is there another way that doesn't require us to enable debug mode and search the page sources?

@WesNolte I will find out more on this and let you know. Thank you

@WesNolte This should still work as per our tests here. Can you tell me what did not work for you?

I made an assumption that I'm guessing was incorrect i.e. if you run the hasLightningWebSecurityEnabled function from the browser console do you expect it to work? Or will this code only work within the JS of a LWC?

It needs to work from inside the LWC @WesNolte! Thank you

Thanks, my assumption was the first function would work from both the browser console or an LWC. Is there a test that works from the browser console?

@WesNolte  Browser console's global object is window.top and any LWS sandbox on the page will have its own global object context. So this is something to always test within the LWC context for LWS.

Great, if we can do that, we could create a browser extension that tells us!
